# Convert iptables rules to firewalld for supporting domain

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I have a list of iptables rules (see below). The main idea of rules replace source ip address for each request on a specific destination IP address. These rules work properly, but in my case the destination host could placed in the cloud and have a dynamic ip, this is a reason why I need a solution which will do the same things as iptables do and also will support fqdn.

My questions

1. Does firewalld support fqdn and an option "nth --every N" ?
2. How to convert these rules for the firewalld?

---

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d api.ipify.org --dport 443 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1  
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d api.ipify.org --dport 443 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2 
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d api.ipify.org --dport 443 -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a tutorial that describes how to convert IPTables commands to firewalld commands
I hope this helps!
https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/security/firewalld/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/427395)